# Unable to donate due to DOB format anomaly

Tags: joomla

I have just created a donate form via Civi. Tried to donate (after logging in as account holder) and completed first from ok. DOB in correct format of

27-09-64 (selected from the pop calendar)

On clicking Confirm Payment the page asking

Please verify the information below carefully

showns - However that is where it has altered the format to

DOB 
09/27/1964

and on clicking Continue I get

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Please select Date of Birth

Can someone tell me how to solve please?

Joomla 3.6.5 - Civicrm 4.7.14

Comment: Thanks for the reply - cannot see reference to uk - screenshot    http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2154069/21671a10ec90d61528b6a7c019ce747c

Comment: firstly - tx Andy for that pointer - i have updated as you outline. Still does not work but I noticed that when I set my date of both in the calendar it shows 27-09-1964 - when i click confirm payment it shows as 27/09/1964. Is this the cause and how do i solve? the first date format i have toi selct from a calendar to choose date - no option to select forward slash

Comment: I changed the Date Format to dd-mm-yyyy but a profile I have still used dd/mm/yyy.  This was because the definition of the date in the custom field set was dd/mm/yyyy.  When I changed this custom field fomat to dd-mm-yyyy then the profile changed - so this overrode the Date Format setting.  You should be able to fix the problem by getting these 2 settings to agree.

Comment: Ok, tx for your patience - I have had no luck yet - these are the 2 screens I have been working on 

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2155431/ff941bc3ceb1f4d48a8e98ab8b6de430

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2155433/0dfe40a01a2a2739bde7e11a12e88c31

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2155444/a23c01e4b8d354520eb887c4db5b661b

These are  the settings - I have tried various settings for birth but no effect. Is there a third area of CiviCrm I should be looking at?

Comment: When you say that you created a donate form in Civi, how did you do it? See this https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19490 - looks likely

Comment: I linked to a contribution page. Anyway, an update to the situation - we explored various settings to no avail. We replicated the problem on our test website - updated the test website to 4.7.16 and it solved the problem. So will now implement that solution on live site. So in summary, never managed to solve problem in 4.7.14 but no problem in 4.7.16.

Answer (score 1):

Have you formatted the date in Administer/Localization/Date Formats? For the UK  'Complete Date' is set to '%B %E, %Y', and 'Complete Date and Time' is set to '%E%f  %B, %Y %l:%M %P'.  Also 'Date Input Fields' is set to 'dd/mm/yyyy' which is probably the critical one in this case.

Comment: Have updated my comments -any more suggestions? this is def the right area